# Fetch Excel particular column value by javascript and give value to textbox

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm fetching whole Excel data in variable `excelRows`, at this time I just want to fetch "SRNO" column 1st value to the textbox

```
function Upload() {
        //Reference the FileUpload element.
        var fileUpload = document.getElementById("ExcelFile");

        //Validate whether File is valid Excel file.
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.xls|.xlsx)$/;
        if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    FillRow(e.target.result);
                };

                reader.readAsBinaryString(fileUpload.files[0]);
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileUpload.files[0]);
            }
            else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a valid Excel file.");
        }
    };

    function FillRow(data) {
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
            type: 'binary'
        });
        var sel_val = document.getElementById("ddlSheetName").value;
        var excelRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sel_val]);

        for (var j = 0; j <= excelRows.length; j++) {
            //how to fetch first value and last value of specific column
        }
    };
```

I'm new to Javascript so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `FillRow` function like this:

```
function FillRow(data) {
    var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
        type: 'binary'
    });

    var sel_val = document.getElementById("ddlSheetName").value;

    //var excelRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sel_val]);

    let excelRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sel_val])
    let firstRow = excelRows[0] // It contains your first row object.

    //how to fetch first value and last value of specific column
    let firstValue = Object.entries(firstRow)[0][1]
};
```

And you can run loops on the `excelRows` object. This one is just an example to fetch the first value.

Comment: Big Thanks Rinkesh Brother! You showed me the path which i follow and succeeded to get value for textbox. ThankYou.. Can't upvote to your answer bcoz of lack of reputation.